# Issue with setting up selenium Grid with docker to run webdriverio tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, webdriver-io

I am trying to set up selenium grid with docker to run my webdriverio tests.  However, I am getting an exception when I execute the tests.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is like:

```
    shub:
    image: "selenium/hub:3.11.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 4444:4444
    environment:
    - GRID_MAX_SESSION="20"
  chromenode:
    image: "selenium/node-chrome:3.11.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 5555
    depends_on:
    - shub
    environment:
    - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=12
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=12
    links:
    - shub
```

The only capability that I am passing through my `wdio.conf.js` file is:

```
browserName: ‘chrome’
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome'
    }
  ]
```

I see in selenium hub container logs that it is up and running:

```
docker-compose logs shub
Attaching to jobz_web_employer_shub_1
shub_1                     | starting selenium hub with configuration:
shub_1                     | {
shub_1                     |   "port": 4444,
shub_1                     |   "role": "hub",
shub_1                     |   "maxSession": "20",
shub_1                     |   "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
shub_1                     |   "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
shub_1                     |   "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
shub_1                     |   "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
shub_1                     |   "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
shub_1                     |   "browserTimeout": 0,
shub_1                     |   "timeout": 30,
shub_1                     |   "debug": false
shub_1                     | }
shub_1                     | 21:01:50.359 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
shub_1                     | 21:01:50.364 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
shub_1                     | 2018-06-22 21:01:51.057:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2354ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
shub_1                     | 21:01:51.833 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running</code>
```

However, when I run my webdriverio tests, I see the exception :

> org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Empty pool of VM for
>   setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true,
>   javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs:
>   org.openqa.selenium.logging..., requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio,
>   url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.12.0}, rotatable: true}

Any idea on what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The exception mentioned

> org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Empty pool of VM for
>   setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true,
>   javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs:
>   org.openqa.selenium.logging..., requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio,
>   url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.12.0}, rotatable: true}

means that your Selenium Grid doesn't have any node available with a browser that has the desired capabilities.

If you're running Selenium Grid as a hub on your machine `(-role hub)` make sure that at least one node which provides the desired browser is connected to that hub. Check out http://localhost:4444/grid/console to see whether any nodes are connected to your hub.

You can also try removing the `-role hub` from the grid configuration and trying again.